# Gmail API's intermittently failing with 400 "precondition check failed"

Tags: google-oauth, gmail-api

Our application creates and deletes Gmail filters on behalf of end users who authorize via OAuth.  Approx. 5% of these requests fail with code 400 and message "precondition check failed".

We've ensured that the filters we are trying to create are valid via testing in our personal Gmail accounts.  As this point we are pretty stumped.  Is there any way to get additional information regarding the root cause of these failures?  I've included our code for creating filters below.

```js
   await this.checkCredentialPreconditions(credential);
    await this.initialize();
    await this.throttle.take(5);
    try {
      await gapi.client.gmail.users.settings.filters.create({
        access_token: credential.accessToken,
        userId: request.userId,
        key: this.apiKey,
        resource: {
          action: {
            addLabelIds: request.addLabelIds,
            removeLabelIds: request.removeLabelIds,
          },
          criteria: {
            excludeChats: true,
            query: request.query,
          },
        },
      });
    } catch (err: unknown) {
      console.error(err);
      throw err;
    }
```

Comment: "precondition check failed"  I have only seen that error with service accounts before its normally an issue with delegation.   How are you authorizing this call?

Comment: Hi @LindaLawton-DaImTo .  We are authorizing this call using a web application client ID.  Our application does not use service accounts.

Comment: @JordanGaston were you able to figure this out? we are facing same Error percentage from October 16th for Gmail Api -'SendMessage' method. if you can please share what worked for you?

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo can you please review this question again, i am facing same issue since Oct16th as well. it is occurring very randomly. Using Gmail API , oauth authorized user, for method 'Messages.Send'